# How to join two tables, apply where on both tables , apply pagination with bookshelf node js

Tags: node.js, bookshelf.js, bookshelf-pagemaker

I have two tables mentioned below:
Reports
Id |status
1  |Active

Reports_details
Id| Cntry| State | City
1 | IN   | UP    | Delhi
1 | US   | Texas | Salt lake

Now my requirement is
Select distinct r.Id from Reports r left join Reports_details rd on r.Id=rd.Id where r.status=‘Active’ and contains(city,’”Del*”’)

Note: using contains for full text search

Problem: How to add where clause on both tables Bookshelf Model simultaneously
and how to fetch above query data with pagination

Tried created 2 respective Models with belongs on and hasMany but issue comes when applying where on either Model, it’s not accepting where clause from both table-error:Invalid column name

Appreciate your suggestion on the work around. Thank You